# map currentlocation nullpointerexception andJSON parsing listview not showing

Tags: android, json, google-maps, listview

i made a JSON parser for my android app but the data list doesnt seem to show, logcat shows that the API loaded and data from it has been retrieved

my class:

```
public class IqamahActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap googleMap;
public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
public ListView mDrawerList;  
List<DrawerItem> dataList;
public ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;   
public CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
public CharSequence mTitle;
CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;   
public TextView mActivityHeader; 
public RelativeLayout frame;    
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "https://codingsquared-prod.apigee.net/masaajid?";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_MASAAJID = "masajid";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_MASJIDNAME = "masjidName";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String TAG_DISTANCEMILES = "distanceMiles";
private static final String TAG_WEBSITE = "website";
private static final String TAG_LATITUDE = "latitude";
private static final String TAG_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String TAG_IQAMAH = "iqamah";
private static final String TAG_FAJR = "fajr";
private static final String TAG_DHUHR = "dhuhr";
private static final String TAG_ASR = "asr";
private static final String TAG_MAGHRIB = "maghrib";
private static final String TAG_ISHA = "isha";
private static final String TAG_KHUTBAH = "khutbah";
private static final String TAG_JUMAH = "jumah";
private static final String TAG_KHUTBAH2 = "khutbah2";
private static final String TAG_JUMAH2 = "jumah2";
private static final String TAG_KHUTBAH3 = "khutbah3";
private static final String TAG_JUMAH3 = "jumah3";
private static final String TAG_LASTUPDATED = "lastUpdated";    

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;


private ListView lv;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_iqamah);
    BuildDrawer();  
    initilizeMap();

    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();  

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_iqamah);

    new GetContacts().execute();


}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(IqamahActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_MASAAJID);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String masjidname = c.getString(TAG_MASJIDNAME);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String distancemiles = c.getString(TAG_DISTANCEMILES);
                    String website = c.getString(TAG_WEBSITE);
                    String latitude = c.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
                    String longitude = c.getString(TAG_LONGITUDE);                        
                    String phone = c.getString(TAG_PHONE);
                    String fajr = c.getString(TAG_FAJR);
                    String dhuhr = c.getString(TAG_DHUHR);
                    String asr = c.getString(TAG_ASR);       
                    String maghrib = c.getString(TAG_MAGHRIB);
                    String isha = c.getString(TAG_ISHA);
                    String khutbah = c.getString(TAG_KHUTBAH);
                    String jumah = c.getString(TAG_JUMAH);
                    String khutbah2 = c.getString(TAG_KHUTBAH2);
                    String jumah2 = c.getString(TAG_JUMAH2);
                    String khutbah3 = c.getString(TAG_KHUTBAH3);
                    String jumah3 = c.getString(TAG_JUMAH3);                       
                    String lastupdated = c.getString(TAG_LASTUPDATED);
                    String iqamah = c.getString(TAG_IQAMAH);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_MASJIDNAME, masjidname);
                    contact.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                    contact.put(TAG_DISTANCEMILES, distancemiles);
                    contact.put(TAG_WEBSITE, website);
                    contact.put(TAG_LATITUDE, latitude);
                    contact.put(TAG_LONGITUDE, longitude);
                    contact.put(TAG_PHONE, phone);                        
                    contact.put(TAG_FAJR, fajr);
                    contact.put(TAG_DHUHR, dhuhr);
                    contact.put(TAG_ASR, asr);
                    contact.put(TAG_MAGHRIB, maghrib);
                    contact.put(TAG_ISHA, isha);
                    contact.put(TAG_KHUTBAH, khutbah);
                    contact.put(TAG_JUMAH, jumah);
                    contact.put(TAG_KHUTBAH2, khutbah2);
                    contact.put(TAG_JUMAH2, jumah2);
                    contact.put(TAG_KHUTBAH3, khutbah3);
                    contact.put(TAG_JUMAH3, jumah3);
                    contact.put(TAG_LASTUPDATED, lastupdated);
                    contact.put(TAG_IQAMAH, iqamah);                        

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                IqamahActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.iqamah_list_item, new String[] { TAG_MASJIDNAME, TAG_ADDRESS,
                        TAG_PHONE }, new int[] { R.id.masjidName,
                        R.id.masjidAddress, R.id.masjidNumber });

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

my xml ( sorry its a little messy) :

Activity :

```
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:background="@color/blue" >


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/semc_bg_light" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/action_bar"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@color/blue" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/app_header_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/qpaper_menu"
                        android:text="@string/iqamah_drawer_title"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/qpaper_menu"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_mosques"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/description" />

                </RelativeLayout>   

                <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="@dimen/card_margin">               
                  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/CardView">

                        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/condensed_title" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <com.sahaab.quantumpaperui.widget.GATextView
                                android:id="@id/title_text"
                                style="@style/CondensedTitleText"
                                android:text="" />

                        </LinearLayout>  
                        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:paddingRight="5dp">
                          <fragment
                             android:id="@+id/iqamah_map"
                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                             android:layout_height="240dp"
                             android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <TextView android:text="" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" />           
                        <include layout="@layout/card_shadow" />
                    </LinearLayout>   
                 </FrameLayout>            

                <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="@dimen/card_margin">               
                  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingTop="@dimen/card_margin" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/CardView">

                        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/condensed_title" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <com.sahaab.quantumpaperui.widget.GATextView
                                android:id="@id/title_text"
                                style="@style/CondensedTitleText"
                                android:text="@string/masjid" />

                        </LinearLayout>  
                        <ListView
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/listview_iqamah"/>                     
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/iqamah_listview_text" android:text="" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" />            
                        <include layout="@layout/card_shadow" />
                    </LinearLayout>   
                 </FrameLayout>                                         

            </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>        


    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <include layout="@layout/navigation_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

list item :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/iqamah_itemLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="1dp"
              android:background="@color/card_shadow"/>
        <LinearLayout android:background="@color/blue" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.0">
            <TextView android:textSize="30.0sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/masjidName" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip" android:layout_weight="0.0" />
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingRight="5dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1.0">
                <TextView android:textSize="12.0sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:layout_gravity="right" android:id="@+id/masjidAddress" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginTop="3.0dip" android:singleLine="true" />
                <TextView android:textSize="12.0sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:layout_gravity="right" android:id="@+id/masjidNumber" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:singleLine="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>     
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="1dp"
              android:background="@color/card_shadow"/>         
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/timings" android:background="@color/main_background" android:paddingLeft="5.0dip" android:paddingRight="5.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1.0">
            <LinearLayout android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1.0">
                <TextView android:text="@string/fajr" android:textColor="@color/text_color_default" android:ellipsize="marquee" android:id="@+id/fajr_iqamah_name" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
                <TextView android:textColor="@color/text_color_default" android:id="@+id/fajr_iqamah_time" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:layout_weight="0.0" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1.0">
                <TextView android:text="@string/dhuhr" android:textColor="@color/text_color_default" android:ellipsize="marquee" android:id="@+id/dhuhr_iqamah_name" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
                <TextView android:textColor="@color/text_color_default" android:id="@+id/dhuhr_iqamah_time" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:layout_weight="0.0" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1.0">
                <TextView android:text="@string/asr" android:textColor="@color/text_color_default" android:ellipsize="marquee" android:id="@+id/asr_iqamah_name" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
                <TextView android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:id="@+id/asr_iqamah_time" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:layout_weight="0.0" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1.0">
                <TextView android:text="@string/maghrib" android:textColor="@color/text_color_default" android:ellipsize="marquee" android:id="@+id/maghrib_iqamah_name" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
                <TextView android:textColor="@color/text_color_default" android:id="@+id/maghrib_iqamah_time" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:layout_weight="0.0" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1.0">
                <TextView android:text="@string/isha" android:textColor="@color/text_color_default" android:ellipsize="marquee" android:id="@+id/isha_iqamah_name" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
                <TextView android:textColor="@color/text_color_default" android:id="@+id/isha_iqamah_time" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:layout_weight="0.0" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="1dp"
              android:background="@color/card_shadow"/>    
</LinearLayout>
```

Screen Shot :
sorry cant add screenshot here
http://s30.postimg.org/tvu3z8m4x/Screenshot_2014_06_28_00_36_23.png

***Map problem***

i have this code to get the current location and move map to that location
but this code sometimes shows a location i was previously at and not currently at, and also for some reason it has now starting Force closing

```
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =  (SupportMapFragment)
            fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.iqamah_map);
        googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();           

        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // false to disable



        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();


        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);


        // Getting Current Location
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

//            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
//                    new LatLng(17.385044, 78.486671)).zoom(12).build();

//            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        url = "https://codingsquared-prod.apigee.net/masaajid?lat="+Double.toString(latitude)+"&long="+Double.toString(longitude);

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        TextView txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.iqamah_listview_text);
        txtview.setText("latitude="+Double.toString(latitude)+" longitude="+Double.toString(longitude));

        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));


    }

}
```

logcat :

```
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sahaab.android.muslimzone.test/com.sahaab.muslimzone.activity.IqamahActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477):    at com.sahaab.muslimzone.activity.IqamahActivity.initilizeMap(IqamahActivity.java:155)
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477):    at com.sahaab.muslimzone.activity.IqamahActivity.onCreate(IqamahActivity.java:103)
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-28 01:05:01.554: E/AndroidRuntime(13477):    ... 12 more
```

also tried for current location :

```
        Location myLocation = googleMap.getMyLocation();
        LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(),
                myLocation.getLongitude());

        CameraPosition myPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(myLatLng).zoom(17).bearing(90).tilt(30).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(
            CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(myPosition));
```

Comment: i tried guides from 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/
and
http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/listview-from-json-example.html
both didnt work

Comment: no error :-/ 
just saw on logcat that i got a response from the site

Comment: it showing error in 155 line of IqamahActivity.java.. which line is that

Comment: that is for the map
it is line : double latitude = location.getLatitude();

Comment: i cannot access the listview anymore due to the map Force closing :-/

Comment: the FC's for map started after i turned on GPS, before i was using google location service

Comment: hmm ya im trying to fix it, but cant figure it out :-/